# Ambiguous interface when using optional arguments in Gfortran

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I've just stumbled across this error when compiling a bit of code that I've been using without problems for ages now. I'm using Gfortran 8.2 on Linux and I suspect that a compiler update has caused the issue.

When I define an interface with an optional argument that has a different number of non-optional arguments, Gfortran complains that the interface is ambiguous. For example, if I compile the following, I get "Ambiguous interfaces in generic interface 'test' for ‘testinit1’ at (1) and ‘testinit2’ at (2)":

```
module test_mod
implicit none

interface Test
    module procedure test1, test2
end interface

contains

function test1(opt) result(rslt)
    integer :: rslt
    integer, optional :: opt
    rslt = 1
end function

function test2(data, opt) result(rslt)
    integer :: rslt
    integer :: data
    integer, optional :: opt
    rslt = data
end function

end module
```

If I remove the optional argument `opt`, then it compiles fine. If I add a `data` argument to `test1` that has a different rank to `test2`'s data, then it compiles fine. If I add another non-optional argument to both functions, I get the same error message.

The actual code I stumbled across in is the `Result` interface in [this file](https://github.com/samharrison7/fortran-error-handler/blob/master/src/Result.f90), which, as I say, used to compile as expected.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: I'm surprised that this would have worked in previous versions of `gfortran`. After all, if you call `Test(23)` do you want to call `test1` with 23 being `opt`, or do you want to call `test2` with 23 being `data` and no `opt`? That's the very definition of ambiguous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Gfortran complains that the interface is ambiguous

Well, that's because the interface **is** ambiguous.
Which procedure should be chosen in the following call?

```
integer :: param
print *, Test(param)
```

1. `test1` with the argument `opt` opted-in? Or...
2. `test2` with the argument `data` passed and `opt` opted-out?

If it started to fail only after an update, that was probably a very welcome bug-fix.

> If I remove the optional argument opt, then it compiles fine. If I add a data argument to test1 that has a different rank to test2's data, then it compiles fine.

Makes sense. Without the optional argument, both functions are completely unambiguous by number of arguments. Changing the rank of the argument also cause differentiation.

> If I add another non-optional argument to both functions, I get the same error message.

Same problem. If both functions had an extra non-optional argument with type-kind-rank conformance, how would you resolve the call?
Suppose the new argument is `data_extra`:

```
print*, Test(param1, param2)
```

1. `test1` with the argument `data_extra` passed and `opt` opted-in? Or...
2. `test2` with the arguments `data` and `data_extra` passed and `opt` opted-out?

Comment: Fair point! My thinking was that in the cases you highlight, it is the _call_ that's ambiguous and not the interface itself. E.g. you should call by `Test(data=stuff)` and `Test(opt=stuff)`. Then calling `Test(stuff)` should default to the argument being the non-optional one.

Interestingly, the latest Intel Fortran also _doesn't_ complain about it.